# Confidence interval for Ratio of slope in linear regression

Tags: linear-regression, confidence-interval

The question I'm trying to solve is as follows;

"Company-wide, one unit of TV advertising on the above coded scale would cost $3, 250, 000. The Vice President for Marketing wants to know how many market share points we get per million dollars spent. Give a 95% confidence interval for this quantity."

I meant to use my answer from the previous question where I calculated the 95% CI for this same slope (B2 corresponding to TV advertising). So, my thinking says I need the confidence interval for B2/3.25. But to do that I need the Standard error of B2/3.25. Is that as simple as SE(B2)/3.25? I'm not sure there's any other way to calculate it. [Link to the full question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3WEf.png)